# How to access page URL with XPath?

Tags: xpath

Is there any possibility to address with XPath a page URL, which appears only in the browser address bar (not in the `head` or `body`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can access with XPath the nodes in the document. Nothing else.

Determining a URL depends on what tools you're using and what you want to achieve, XPath alone won't help you.

Comment: Related: In the browser from JavaScript, the page URL is available via `window.location.href`.